# What options are available to report the build status of Jenkins Multi Pipeline's first branch build on k8s to bitbucket-cloud?

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, builds, bcbsn

**Background**

[The Bitbucket Status Notifier plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/bitbucket-build-status-notifier) has been configured. The status was reported, but since more and more jobs have been moved to Jenkins-on-steroids that is running on k8s, buildStats are not reported if a branch is built for the first time.

**Aim**

The aim is to report the build status to bitbucket-cloud by jenkins multi-branch when a branch is built for the first time.

**Attempts to solve the issue**

[This related issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-40456) was found and [a comment was added](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-40456?focusedCommentId=318401&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-318401) on Jenkins' Jira.

As a workaround, this suggestion was tried, but it caused a couple of issues and it is not a permanent solution.

> ```
> def call(buildId, jobName) {
>     if ("${buildId}" == "1") {
>         build job: "${jobName}", wait: false
>         currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'
>         error("Skipping build ${buildId} as it doesn't play nice with bitbucket notifications")
>     }
> }
> ```

**Questions**

The question is twofold.

- First, what other options are available to report build statuses from jenkins-on-steroids to **bitbucket-cloud** that also work if a build is run for the first time in a branch `(BUILD_ID==1)` if the [multi-branch plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Multibranch+Plugin) is used?
- Second, if the first question cannot be answered, what steps could be taken to solve the bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was not able to tackle the bug in the Java code and the bug was already reported in 2017 I decided to write [this plugin](https://github.com/030/golang-bitbucket-cloud-build-status-notifier). This binary is able to send a build status even when a branch is built for the first time.